# Eclipse install Web Development Tool: conflicing dependencies

Tags: eclipse

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04, Eclipse Oxygen Committers (installed in `/opt`).

I am trying to install the "Eclipse Web Development Tool" package in Eclipse Oxygen, but got the following error messages.

I tried the following:

1. Deleted ~/.eclipse and workspace/.metata directories and re-installed the package again
2. `sudo apt remove eclipse*`
3. Completely removed the `/opt/eclipse` directory and re-install Eclipse again

None of the above attempts worked. So, how to solve the problem? Or, how do I completely remove Eclipse's configurations?

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.9.1.v201707252002 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.1.v201707252002)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.9.0.v201706011851 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201706011851)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    SSE infopops 1.0.300.v201707252002 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop 1.0.300.v201707252002)
    SSE infopops 1.0.300.v201309112106 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop 1.0.300.v201309112106)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.9.1.v201707252002 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.1.v201707252002)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group [3.9.1.v201707252002]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.9.0.v201706011851 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201706011851)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop [1.0.300.v201309112106]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.9.1.v201707252002 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.1.v201707252002)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.infopop [1.0.300.v201707252002]
```

Comment: It looks like the _Eclipse Web Development Tool_ is in conflict with an older version of _Eclipse XML Editors and Tools_. Try to update or uninstall _Eclipse XML Editors and Tools_ (which is contained in the _Eclipse Web Development Tool_) first. How did you try to install it? Via the Eclipse Marketplace client? Alternatively, you can install _Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers_ which contains the _Web Development Tool_.

Comment: But since the XML Editors in in Web development Tool, how do I uninstall the XML Editor before I can install Web development Tool? I also checked "About Eclipse" --> "Installation Details", the "Uninstall" button for `Eclipse XML Editors and Tools` is greyed out.

Comment: In this case, use the [_Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers_](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen1a) package which includes everything you want.